# Selenium webdriver not opening url instead opening a blank page only

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to use selenium webdriver in my java code but it is not opening any url instead it is just opening a blank page. I am using selenium webdriver version 2.48 and firefox version 45.1.0 . I tried installing previous versin of firefox to my redhat but it is not working and giving error
   " libgio-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    Couldn't load XPCOM."
    My java code :

```
FirefoxProfile prof = new FirefoxProfile();
    prof.setPreference("browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone", "ignore");
    prof.setPreference("startup.homepage_welcome_url.additional",  "about:blank");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(prof); 
        //  TestUtils
//.createCrawlDriverForTest(createDefaultCapabilities())
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Can you try using the latest version of Selenium - 2.53?

Comment: there is no error when i run the unit test ! it is just openinig blank firefox.
and when i added print statements ! the print statement after "WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver(prof);" is not printing anything like it is not reaching print statement after this line

Comment: And is it the issue with the version of selenium ? as i donot want to upgrade the verssion as it might break dependencies

Comment: Hi Ram, I executed the same code which you have mentioned and its working for me. I am able to open the page google.com and this is not an issue with the selenium as I am also using selenium - 2.53. Can you upgrade your Firefox version and see whether it is working there or not as I am using Firefox 46.0.1.

Comment: You can try the below code as well to check whether this is working for you or not :
                `FirefoxProfile prof = new FirefoxProfile();`
                   `prof.setPreference("browser.startup.homepage","http://www.google.com");`
     `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(prof); `

Comment: anubhav i am using selenium version 2.48 !

Comment: hey @AnubhavMishra with your code it is opening googlepage initially but when i try to open other by driver.get(url) , nothing is happening.

Comment: Ram can you please share the code what you are using later.

Comment: hey it opened ! i just added a previous version of firefox. :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually selenium 2.48 supports upto firefox version 41 so either i had to update the selenium webdriver version or use an older version of firefox.

using an older version did the trick for me.